# Recursive call in python seems not to descend

Tags: python, recursion, generator, yield

I have a small function to flatten lists and tuples. The recursive call does get invoked, but .. nothing happens.. By "nothing" i mean:  the stderr message is not printed and also no results are yielded. That behavior does not make sense, so pointers appreciated. Thx!

```
def flatten(*arr):
  sys.stderr.write("STDERR: arr is %s\n" %list(arr))
  for a in arr:
    if type(a) is list or type(a) is tuple:
      flatten(a)
    else:
      yield a

print list(flatten(['hi there','how are you'],'well there','what?',[1, 23423,33]))
```

Comment: Is obj a global?  I don't see it defined anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your function.

First of all, use `isinstance()` to simplify the test for sequences:

```
for a in arr:
    if isinstance(a, (list, tuple)):
```

You need to loop over the recursive `flatten()` call to pass the elements on to the caller, and pass in the list as separate arguments (using the `*` syntax, to mirror the function signature):

```
for sub in flatten(*a):
    yield sub
```

With these changes the generator works:

```
>>> def flatten(*arr):
...     for a in arr:
...         if isinstance(a, (list, tuple)):
...             for sub in flatten(*a):
...                 yield sub
...         else:
...              yield a
... 
>>> print list(flatten(['hi there','how are you'],'well there','what?',[1, 23423,33]))
['hi there', 'how are you', 'well there', 'what?', 1, 23423, 33]
```

Comment: If you use python 3.3 you can use yield from instead of looping over the values of your recursive call.

Comment: @oao: yup, but the OP is using Python 2.x (using a `print` statement, not a `print()` function), so I stuck to that.